# how can i make a rig follow a shapekey deformation?

Tags: rigging, shape-keys

Something like Bruce Banner turning into the Hulk.
I have a model with lots of shapekeys to make different characters.
I'm usin the pitchipoy rigify (or any) and i wish that when i modify the model to a desire character the rig  follow the size and shape, so i don't have the need to do it manually everytime.

Comment: Well i think that's the way flexyrig from cgcookie works. i don't know if they explain how they do it in the dvd, and righ now i don have enough money

Comment: How about [this](https://blend-exchange.com/b/woA0ExYs/)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's possible. Editing a rig in animation compromises the relation bone - weights. Mesh weights become wrong and the rig influences it's mesh in a wrong way.

What I've seen in such problematic, is to have two models, each with it's individual rig, and when one model morphs to take the shape of the second, they simply switch the visibility.

Comment: Thaks for reponding. It seems that there is no way to do that. I have to do it manually.  Thanks, again!